# JMeter : 500 Internal server error (calling API)

Tags: ajax, jmeter, performance-testing

Hi Guys does anyone know about 500 internal server error when calling API?

I have an application where one of the functionality gets the data from API 
so, i am doing jmeter perfomance tessting on the functionality

1) I recorded scripts using the jmeter proxy (Https recorder) 
2) i added the listner 
3) ran the script with jus tone thread

I saw 500 Internal server error in Response (please click the below link to see the error screenshot

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcxPC.png)

Is something related to the api server calling using proxy or its problem with my script ?

Please tell any solutions how to do the performance testing on this scenario ?

Comment: 500 response means there is an internal server error (you can see that is the response message in your image). You would have to check the server's error logs to see what the specific error is.

Comment: @newUserName02 .Hi thanks for the reposnse but i checked in the server event logs too but nothing recorded there? Do u know how to record application without using the jmeter proxy recorder?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have enough information to figure out the cause of the failure so I can only give a piece of general advice:

1. Capture the request send to the endpoint by the real browser, you can use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
2. Do the same for JMeter, either inspect request using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or the aforementioned sniffer tools
3. Given requests are the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) or [parameterized](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)) you should be getting the same response

Comment: thanks for the respnse i tried all the things u mentioned and i done correlation and parametriazation as well ( and compared requests  passing ) when recording and when run the scripts . what is the best way to show my scripts ?

Comment: thanks Dmitri fro the suggestions and i used fiddler to see the requests and the responses and figured out am sending the wrong encrypted key extractor value to the requests and that's why my response was getting 500 internal server error.